# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'command' was corrupted не пойму где ошибка. помогите, пожалуйста

Tags: c

````
#include <string.h>

// * / - +

int main()
{
    int res;
    double a;
    double b;
    char command[2];
    scanf_s("%lf", &a);
    scanf_s("%s", command);
    scanf_s("%lf", &b);
    if (command[0] == '/') {
        printf("%lf", a / b);
    }
    if (command[0] == '*') {
        printf("%lf", a * b);
    }
    if (command[0] == '-') {
        printf("%lf", a - b);
    }
    if (command[0] == '+') {
        printf("%lf", a + b);
    }
    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: `scanf_s("%s", command)` выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: не scanf_s("%s", command), а scanf_s("%1s", command). А иначе легко можете вызвать переполнение буфера command.

Comment: `scanf_s` требует еще третий параметр -= размер буфера.

Comment: @LShadow77, помогло только введение массива на 1023 символа